# AWS S3 Boto Download Timing Out on some Jenkins Jobs and Not Others

Tags: python, jenkins, amazon-s3, boto

the problem: I have a python script that is ran via a multi-configuration jenkins job. The job downloads the script and passes parameters to it. It spawns 10 times because there is 10 sets of data that are being loaded in parallel. On some ocasions and not always 2 or 3 out of the jobs will get a s3 timeout error. I'm not sure why because its not always the same jobs and its not all the time.

error:

```
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0124.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0125.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0126.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0127.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0128.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0129.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0130.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0131.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0132.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0133.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0134.json.gz
Downloading: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0135.json.gz
> Downloading:
> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/json_data/wos/20150707/wos_1/WOK5_20150410045810_WOS_0135.json.gz
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/es_single_load.py",
> line 1094, in <module>
>     directory = download_s3(wos_data, 'tr-ips-ses-data',access_key, secret_key)   File
> "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-es-data/label/swarm/wos/wos_1/es_single_load.py",
> line 31, in download_s3
>     l.get_contents_to_filename(d)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1712, in
> get_contents_to_filename
>     response_headers=response_headers)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1650, in
> get_contents_to_file
>     response_headers=response_headers)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1482, in
> get_file
>     query_args=None)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1535, in
> _get_file_internal
>     for bytes in self:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 386, in next
>     data = self.resp.read(self.BufferSize)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 413, in
> read
>     return http_client.HTTPResponse.read(self, amt)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 573, in read
>     s = self.fp.read(amt)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
>     data = self._sock.recv(left)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 714, in recv
>     return self.read(buflen)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 608, in read
>     v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024) ssl.SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',) Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as
> failure Finished: FAILURE
```

python:

```
def download_s3(wos,bucket, access_key, secret_key):
    # connect to the bucket
    conn = boto.connect_s3(access_key, secret_key)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket)
    LOCAL_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bucket_list = bucket.list()
    for l in bucket_list:
        keyString = str(l.key)
        d = LOCAL_PATH + '/' + keyString
        search_string = '/' + wos + '/'
        if search_string in str(l) and '20150707' in str(l):
            if str(wos) == 'wos_1' and '/wos_10/' in str(l):
                continue
            try:
                print 'Downloading: %s' % d
                l.get_contents_to_filename(d)
            except OSError:
                if not os.path.exists(d):
                    os.makedirs(d)
        else:
            continue

    conn.close()
    return d,LOCAL_PATH
```

Comment: Have you tried spawning less than 10 jobs to see if there's a difference? If that was my problem to debug, I run the job with n == 1..10, and see where the problems start to manifest. Also, do you always run the job at the same time/day-of-week? What other processes are being run that may influence your job?

Comment: @boardrider Its just a manual run job currently while im testing. After doing more testing I noticed its a particular file the file size is 21.2mb and its just one job now that is timing out and it times out on the same file every pass. I wrote a self healing portion of the script that fixes all but this one file and this one file has the same permissions as the rest.

Comment: So, maybe it's just certain parts of the file that give you grief: try the "lion in the desert" hunting method - to pinpoint the exact places.